# Unable to retrieve session value

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

On page load I am populating my own list object, storing in session & it is getting stored, When I am debugging i can see that list object is stored in session, But When I am reading that session variable in next page, it's throwing error like

The type 'Dispensary.ResourceScheduling.Views.SchedulingPopup' exists in both 'WebApplication.dll' and 'App_Web_6bndsqgu.dll'

So Can u please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do a full rebuild on your project.
If that still doesn't work, delete everything in the `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\[mywebsite]` folder, where `[mywebsite]` is the name of your project.  If the DLLs are locked you will have to stop and restart the website in IIS.

Occasionally I've noticed that Visual Studio gets confused and leaves behind the temporary DLLs.  This doubles up your classes but is has nothing to do with session values.

Answer (score 1):

You have corrupted .NET temporary files. Before the full rebuild or anything else, do a "Clean Solution". This reliably cleans up .NET temporary files, plus any other accumulated sludge.

Corrupted .NET temporary files can occur from a number of situations, most notably editing binding expressions mixed into markup in .aspx pages. The key to identifying .NET temporary file problems is an obfuscated file name, such as "App_Web_6bndsqgu.dll". Problems can include duplicate .dlls (as noted), inability to find or load some pages and services dynamically (ASP.NET-hosted WCF services are vulnerable to this), and more. So "clean solution" is the first thing to reach for when any of these happen.

When working with source control, it's my basic practice now to do "get latest", "clean solution", and "rebuild solution" before any further work.